# SELECT multiple rows WHERE matching four or more conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a problem with my php code select, 
  I want to select a row from a table where four conditions is meet.

```
$course = $_GET['Course'];
$year_enrolled = $_GET['Year_Enrolled'];
$month = $_GET['Month'];
$year = $_GET['Year'];

$sql=" SELECT * FROM dtr WHERE Course like '%$course%' OR Year_enrolled like '%$year_enrolled%' AND Month like '%$month%' OR Year like '%$year%'";
```

Comment: This is possible. But how can we answer without seeing the SQL you are using?

Comment: You might want to edit your question to include your code.

Comment: $course = $_GET['Course'];
        $year_enrolled = $_GET['Year_Enrolled'];
 $month = $_GET['Month'];
 $year = $_GET['Year'];
 
$sql=" SELECT * FROM dtr WHERE Course like '%$course%' OR Year_enrolled like '%$year_enrolled%' AND Month like '%$month%' OR Year like '%$year%'";

Comment: sorry about that its my first time posting a question. please help.

Comment: Consider storing years and months (and days) using the date data type.

Comment: You need to use parenthesis when mixing and/or clauses. Figure out which should go together.

Comment: ill try that. is it possible to make my code work.?

Comment: i actually try the code with two conditions and it work by using the or. but when i add another condition, it just show everything.

Comment: Which conditions go together? Is it `WHERE course OR (year_enrolled AND month) OR Year`? If so, that's where you need the parenthesis. If not, then you need to figure out which clauses need to go together, and which do not.

Comment: thanks aynber ill try it that way.

Comment: strawberry can I use the date data type as a condition? if I replace the month and year. sense its a date format.?

Comment: aynber you save me. WHERE course or year_enrolled and (month or year) it work this way... thanks a lot man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Code Gives me accurate result for this kind of problem.

```
$sql= " SELECT * FROM dtr WHERE Course like '%$course%' AND Year_enrolled like '%$year_enrolled%' AND (Month like '%$month%' AND Year like '%$year%')";
```